# How to manipulate pyplot histogram xtick labels?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I plot a histogram, values are read from 'input.txt'.

```
f=np.recfromtxt('input.txt')
plt.hist(f[:,0],bins=[1E+27,1E+28,1E+29,1E+30, 1E+31,1E+32,1E+33])
plt.xlabel('x-axis label',fontsize=30)
plt.ylabel('Number of Sources',fontsize=30, style='italic')
plt.gca().set_xscale("log")
plt.xticks([1E+27,1E+28,1E+29,1E+30, 1E+31,1E+32,1E+33], labels, align="center" )
plt.tick_params(labelsize=25,align='center' )
labels = ['','$10^{28}$','$10^{29}$','$10^{30}$','$10^{31}$','$10^{32}$','$10^{33}$']
plt.show()
```

but despite the `align='center'` command, the tick labels are still not centered. Is there a way to center them?

Comment: Try using `align='left'` as a parameter to `hist()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see align parameter amongst tick_params here
http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params

Instead specify alignment of ticks  explicitly for each axis using set_xticklabels mehtod for X axis
(http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels) and assign the "ha" parameter (horizontal alignment parameter) 'center' value. set_yticklabels works pretty much the same